# java titlebar modification

Tags: java, user-interface, titlebar

I'd like to change the color of the java titlebar and add some text to the ends and the middle.

The previous coder used setUndecorated(false) and a JPanel to achieve this effect but I am trying to change this to modify the actual title bar because the panel solution is an issue with menus and focus.

tl;dr Want to change the color of the titlebar and set text in the middle and one the ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can change the title bar color with the method described here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/346141/GUI/java/set-JFrame-titlebar-color

Changing the text should be possible via [setTitle()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). You can call this method as many times as you want throughout the life of the application to change the title text on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This worked for the color but sadly I can't use the real titlebar apparently because the customer doesn't want the X icon on the windows. *sigh* back to the drawing board.

Comment: JFrame's `setUndecorated(boolean)` method will allow you to remove the title bar altogether, then add a `JLabel`, which contains text that you can style anyway you like. Customers make funny requests. Sometimes your role is to tell them no, or tell them how much more it will cost to remove the 'X'.

Comment: JLabel image example: http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&client=firefox-a&sa=N&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&authuser=0&biw=1214&bih=799&tbm=isch&tbnid=G5w_685NgEFreM:&imgrefurl=http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpledemonstrationoftextalignmentinJLabels.htm&docid=Xl7MJwFQBJaWvM&imgurl=http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/JLabel2D.PNG&w=600&h=300&ei=GTPRTriOOISc2AW1p4CxDw&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=262&vpy=319&dur=1929&hovh=159&hovw=318&tx=163&ty=100&sig=111619896268144804206&page=1&tbnh=90&tbnw=179&start=0&ndsp=23&ved=1t:429,r:6,s:0

Comment: I'm not even high enough in the chain of command to talk to the customer, let alone tell them no. Have something similar to that already(its a JPanel instead of a label) but the JMenuBar appears above it if I attach it to the dialog and there are focus issues if attached to an internal frame inside the dialog(the previous developers solution)